# How to convert string with format HH:MM:SS into NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Stored time in the string format HH:MM:SS from json responce. I want to convert it NSDate for local notification.
tried 
 NSString *datestr = @"21:00:00";

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateformat dateFromString:datestr];



NSLog(@"time is %@",date);
```

Getting Null time. I have time format from json is in 21:00:00 format only no date. I want to set this time for Local Notification everyday.

Comment: Hint: your hours are in 24-hour format, not 12-hour format. Please read the spec on date formatters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HH` if the hours part of your string ranges from 0 to 23. [This site has a convenient list of date formatter codes.](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Then you'll want to convert the date into `NSDateComponents` so you can create a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSDateFormatter *parser;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    parser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    parser.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
    parser.calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
}

- (void)createRepeatingNotificationAtTimeOfDay:(NSString *)timeOfDay {
    NSDate *date = [parser dateFromString:timeOfDay];
    if (date == nil) {
        // Couldn't parse the string.
        return;
    }

    NSDateComponents *components = [parser.calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];
    if (components == nil) {
        // Couldn't extract components.
        return;
    }

    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = @"Daily alarm";
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"dailyalarm" content:content trigger:trigger];
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```